# QWC2 Docker - access PostgresSQL docker in QGIS on Ubuntu for project in \qgsresources\scan directory

Tags: postgresql, qgis-web-client, docker, qwc2

In QWC Docker - I can access PostgreSQL on the localhost but I can not access the docker PostgreSQL. Do I need to run QGIS in the docker? or add something else to this?

[image]

[image]

I can see it is the docker-compose up -d but not in the docker ps

```
gis@vmi1:/GIS/QWC/qwc-docker$ sudo docker-compose up -d
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-auth-service_1            ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-mapinfo-service_1         ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-feature-info-service_1    ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-postgis_1                 ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-config-service_1          ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-legend-service_1          ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-map-viewer_1              ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-elevation-service_1       ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-permalink-service_1       ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-solr_1                    ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-data-service_1            ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-qgis-server_1             ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-fulltext-search-service_1 ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-admin-gui_1               ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-ogc-service_1             ... done
Recreating qwc-docker_qwc-api-gateway_1             ... done
gis@vmi1:/GIS/QWC/qwc-docker$ sudo docker -ps
```

Here's the Docker PS

```
gis@vmi1:/GIS/QWC/qwc-docker$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                              NAMES
8800dfe7f701   nginx:1.19                                           "/docker-entrypoint.…"   31 seconds ago   Up 29 seconds             0.0.0.0:8088->80/tcp               qwc-docker_qwc-api-gateway_1
a2e4c3c20209   sourcepole/qwc-data-service:v2022.02.03              "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5012->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-data-service_1
a84eee435d18   sourcepole/qwc-fulltext-search-service:v2022.01.27   "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5011->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-fulltext-search-service_1
d33fff3f3656   sourcepole/qwc-ogc-service:v2022.01.27               "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5013->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-ogc-service_1
3e73acf11e58   sourcepole/qwc-qgis-server:3.16-plugins              "/sbin/my_init"          34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:8001->80/tcp             qwc-docker_qwc-qgis-server_1
4c4c5ddfdccd   sourcepole/qwc-admin-gui:v2022.01.27                 "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5031->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-admin-gui_1
47a38d411f38   solr:8.11.1-slim                                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:8983->8983/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-solr_1
9a97f3598f0d   sourcepole/qwc-elevation-service:v2022.01.27         "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5002->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-elevation-service_1
4ed991bb6db2   sourcepole/qwc-permalink-service:v2022.01.27         "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5001->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-permalink-service_1
2e551d776206   sourcepole/qwc-demo-db:v2022.01.27                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds (healthy)   127.0.0.1:5439->5432/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-postgis_1
6e6e146646d5   sourcepole/qwc-map-viewer-demo:v2022.02.03           "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5030->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-map-viewer_1
5adbaa6ce1fa   sourcepole/qwc-config-generator:v2022.02.03          "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5010->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-config-service_1
92186c6d00fa   sourcepole/qwc-legend-service:v2022.01.27            "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5014->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-legend-service_1
7150818231f5   sourcepole/qwc-feature-info-service:v2022.01.27      "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5015->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-feature-info-service_1
c3133085be06   sourcepole/qwc-mapinfo-service:v2022.01.27           "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 31 seconds             127.0.0.1:5016->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-mapinfo-service_1
b2ebf761ccae   sourcepole/qwc-db-auth:v2022.01.27                   "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   34 seconds ago   Up 32 seconds             127.0.0.1:5017->9090/tcp           qwc-docker_qwc-auth-service_1
ea5057a843e7   gisquick/settings                                    "./server"               15 hours ago     Up About an hour          8001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8002->8002/tcp   gisquick_go_1
7d8c903db454   gisquick/qgis-server:3.4                             "/usr/bin/supervisor…"   15 hours ago     Up About an hour          0.0.0.0:90->90/tcp                 gisquick_qgisserver_1
e08c3c053de1   gisquick/django                                      "supervisord -c /etc…"   15 hours ago     Up About an hour          0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp             gisquick_django_1
bb66d3d2799b   nginx                                                "/docker-entrypoint.…"   15 hours ago     Up About an hour          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                 gisquick_nginx_1
gis@vmi1:/GIS/QWC/qwc-docker$
```

Setup as per https://github.com/qwc-services/qwc-docker#adding-qgis-projects

---- UPDATE

```
        Name                 Command             State              Ports       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
qwc-docker_qwc-        /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
admin-gui_1            --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-api-    /docker-               Up             0.0.0.0:8088-      
gateway_1              entrypoint.sh ngin                    >80/tcp,:::8088-   
                       ...                                   >80/tcp            
qwc-docker_qwc-auth-   /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
service_1              --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-        /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
config-service_1       --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-data-   /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
service_1              --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-        /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
elevation-service_1    --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-        /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
feature-info-          --http-so ...                                            
service_1                                                                       
qwc-docker_qwc-        /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
fulltext-search-       --http-so ...                                            
service_1                                                                       
qwc-docker_qwc-        /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
legend-service_1       --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-map-    /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
viewer_1               --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-        /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
mapinfo-service_1      --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-ogc-    /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
service_1              --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-        /bin/sh -c uwsgi       Up                                
permalink-service_1    --http-so ...                                            
qwc-docker_qwc-        docker-entrypoint.sh   Up (healthy)   127.0.0.1:5439-    
postgis_1              postgres                              >5432/tcp          
qwc-docker_qwc-qgis-   /sbin/my_init          Up             80/tcp             
server_1                                                                        
qwc-docker_qwc-        docker-entrypoint.sh   Exit 1                            
solr_1                 solr- ...
```

Comment: What is the result of `docker-compose ps -a`?

Comment: @swiss_knight - I have added the result.

Answer (score 1):

This may not fully answer your question, but the "host" needs to be the host machine. In a typical postgis connection that is where I put the IP addres or URL. I am assuming if it was on your local computer it would be "localhost".

Also I see in the default docker compose file it looks like the ip address mapped is 127.0.0.1:5439:5432 - I am assuming this means you'd connect to 127.0.0.1 to get to port 5432 in the container?

I am having this issue myself and havnt solved it so these are some thoughts.

Comment: Thanks Devin. I am not sure. QGIS is obviously outside the container, so in the db connection in QGIS, how do we refer to the postgres created by the qwc docker?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but for future folks, you can access PostGIS running in Docker from the host machine on 127.0.0.1 port 5439, which re-directs to port 5432 in the docker container where PostGIS is running.

You can tell this from the docker ps output:
qwc-docker_qwc-        docker-entrypoint.sh   Up (healthy)   127.0.0.1:5439-
postgis_1              postgres                              >5432/tcp

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to create a .pg_service.conf file in /home/user/.pg_service.conf with the following content:

[qwc_configdb]
host=localhost
port=5439
dbname=qwc_services
user=qwc_admin
password=qwc_admin
sslmode=disable

[qwc_geodb]
host=localhost
port=5439
dbname=qwc_services
user=qwc_service_write
password=qwc_service_write
sslmode=disable

[qgisprojects]
host=localhost
port=5439
dbname=qwc_services
user=qwc_service_write
password=qwc_service_write
sslmode=disable

Then you can connect to the postgis with the service informacion.